# Can't Fill Circle...?

Tags: mesh

I'm just trying to make one circle... But when I put it down and set the fill to "Ngon" nothing happens...
[image: What I see with fill on ngon]

Comment: You are in wireframe mode, that's why you don't see the face.

Answer (score 2):

Are you in edit mode or object mode? If it says object mode in the bottom tab, press TAB to go to edit mode, usually you can fill using F.

If you're in wireframe mode you can't see the faces, Z is the default shortcut to enter and get out of wireframe

Comment: Thanks! I messed around and it must have been a bug, as editing and exiting edit mode eventually solved it. =P